# What is the definition of a sufficiently ample line bundle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I find this concept in Kollar and Mori's book {\em Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties}, but cant search the precise definition in the book or google. Can you tell me the definition? Thanks for any comments or references.

Comment: Maybe you should say  where precisely in the book you found this concept...

Comment: A wild guess is that for any ample line bundle $L$, there exists some $N$, such that for all $n\geq N$, $L^{\otimes n}$ is sufficiently ample. This "definition" only makes sense if the term is used in certain contexts like "If $L$ is sufficiently ample, then .." and not "If ..., then $L$ is sufficiently ample."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many theorems of the form

> **Theorem Frame**
>   If something holds and $\mathscr L$ is an ample line bundle, then there exists an $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, something else holds with $\mathscr L^{\otimes n}$ in it.

You should think of things like

- a sheaf being generated by global sections
- Serre vanishing
- transversality statements
- avoiding certain points or properties
- etc.

*Sufficiently ample* means that whatever they are claiming holds  for $\mathscr L^{\otimes n}$ for all $n\geq n_0$ with some $n_0\in \mathbb N$ for any ample line bundle $\mathscr L$.